# Print RichTextBox text to Migradoc document

Tags: c#, migradoc

I'm using Migradoc to print a series of PDF pages. I also have a RichTextBox from the Extended WPF Toolkit.  The text is currently using the rtf encoding and is bound to a string property.

I have already seen this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13986397/978622.
It appears to convert the generated XPS to an entire PDF page. I'd like to use the textbox content within a page.

How can I print the formatted text from the textbox with Migradoc?  I've

I'm willing to consider using any rich textbox that allows binding & serialization of the data if it makes printing with Migradoc easier.